# How to replace IN clause with JOIN in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query.

```
select * 
from table table0_ 
where (table0_.col1, table0_.col2, table0_.col3) in (($1, $2, $3) , ($4, $5, $6) , ($7, $8, $9) , ($10, $11, $12) , ($13, $14, $15))
```

How to replace IN clause with JOIN as shown in the below in the Postgres.

```
select * 
from table0_ 
where table0_.col1=$1 
  and table0_.col2=$2 
  and table0_.col3=$3
```

EDIT: I read from somewhere that IN operator does not make use of indexes. Also, this query is taking more time if passing more parameters.

Comment: you can't blindly replace an IN with a JOIN - they are doing different things. Why do you want to do that? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited the question. I am trying to improve the query performance.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query? Without that information it will be very hard to see what the problem is for the query and how to optimize performance. The DDL for this table, including the indexes, would be helpful as well

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you should do that because actually no difference between them. You can use the below query and use `CTE` to create a temp table and join together.

```sql
with data as (
  select 
    *
  from (
    values ($1, $2, $3) , ($4, $5, $6) , ($7, $8, $9) , ($10, $11, $12) , ($13, $14, $15)
  ) t (col1, col2, col3)
)
select 
  table0_.*
from 
  table0_, data
where 
  table0_.col1 = data.col1
  and table0_.col2 = data.col2
  and table0_.col3 = $data.col3
```